# On android 6.0.1 there's no more DAILY data usage limit setting

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, mobile-data, data-connection, data-monitoring

I've got a daily plan. 1GB each day.
I wanted to set daily data usage for my phone and i remember there was a daily option on android 4 but now there's no option to change.. only monthly. This is so silly.

Also, third party apps now are not able to block data when the counter reaches a certain amount. This means that if i have a daily plan i cannot stop the connection if it reaches a certain amount.

I am missing something here? Hope so.

Comment: What you're missing is that data services are a profit center for your provider. It is not advantageous for them to give you tools to minimize their getting more money from you through your overages. They may have decided the tool was self-defeating.

Comment: I don't understand why android should change the setting, it (apparently) has nothing to do with providers

Comment: Is there not an app that could change your settings to turn off mobile data and disable wifi - i haven't checked to be honest but i feel like that'd be worth having and so there's surely 10 of them out there by now :)